# Push this into an array onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push data into an array when I do an onClick event.

```
function clickCard() {
    $(document).on('click', '.card', function() {
        $(this).addClass('visible');

        var cardValue = $(this).attr('src');
        matchOrNot.push(cardValue);

    })
}
```

I'm trying to get the src of an image into the array and it needs to be that specific image (this) that I clicked on. Hope it makes sense.

When I try this I get 'undefined' of the variable matchOrNot.

This function works if I target a selector with a notation [0] but I want to get this.

Any idéas?

Comment: `matchOrNot` is not defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Better forget `this`. Use `function(e) { let $this = $(e.currentTarget) /* rest of the code */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var A = []

  $('.card').on('click', e => {
      let $this = $(e.currentTarget)
      $this.addClass('visible')
      let cardValue = $this.attr('src');
      A.push(cardValue);
      
      console.log(A)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="card" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
<img class="card" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000" />
```

**Update:**

After seeing your code I got the problem. Not `matchOrNot` is undefined, but the `src` attribute, as your current target is not the image but an outer `div`. You need to find the image within first:

```
$this.find('img').attr('src')
```

Comment: Your solution works great when I run the code snippet. I don't really get it to work. I changed the code a bit and got the addClass to work but when I click a card it still console.logs "undefined".

Comment: @TomÖst 1) How is `matchOrNot` defined? 2) How is `clickCard` called?

Comment: matchOrNot is a global variable.

`function clickCard() {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.card' , e => {
            let $this = $(e.currentTarget)
            $this.addClass('visible')
            let cardValue = $this.attr('src');
            matchOrNot.push(cardValue);
    
            console.log(matchOrNot)

    })

    })
}
`

Comment: @TomÖst I have asked for how `clickCard` is **called** not how it is defined!

Comment: I'm doing a memory game that gets data from the pokéApi. I have three buttons that load the amounts of cards depending on the difficulty level. So when I click on game level it does this: 

`$(document).on('click', '#easy', function() {
    for (var cards = 0; cards < easy; cards++) { 
        getData();
    }
    disableButtons();   
    clear();
    startGame();
    clickCard();
 
})`

Comment: When you choose the level the second time, you will have duplicated event handlers. You don't need to add those handlers again, as `$(document).on('click', '.card'...` will work for all elements matching the filter (`.card` in your case) including the ones created later.

Comment: I just started to study so I'm very new to this but I don't really follow you. My code is here: [link](https://github.com/tomost2019/MixMatch) I'm sure there are tons of wrong about it haha but I'm here to learn!

Comment: @TomÖst see my update. However: call `clickCard()` only once somewhere at the beginning of your code flow, even if there are no `.card` elements yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the object src with the class .card when using `$(this)`, the fastest solution would be to use a `$('#id')` to get the image src.

Answer (score 0):

The given click event i.e. click event on element with class `'card'` should get registered when DOM is ready for interaction, and the place for that is $(document).ready() method. 
Please wrap `$(document).on` inside ready event.
This should fix the issue.